# AWS Route 53 with Boto: alias target name does not lie within the target zone

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-route53

I am trying to update existing alias_dns_name to different new elb using python boto '2.38.0'

```
def a_record_alias_update(myRegion, myDomain, elbName, elbZone):
dnsConn = route53.connect_to_region(myRegion)
myZone = dnsConn.get_zone(myDomain+'.')
changes = route53.record.ResourceRecordSets(dnsConn,myZone.id)
add_change_args_upsert = {
    'action': 'UPSERT',
    'name': 'dev.'+myDomain+'.',
    'type': 'A',
    'alias_hosted_zone_id': elbZone,
    'alias_dns_name': elbName,
    'alias_evaluate_target_health': True
}
change = changes.add_change(**add_change_args_upsert)
result = changes.commit()
return result
```

Error:

```
result = changes.commit()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/route53/record.py", line 168, in commit
return self.connection.change_rrsets(self.hosted_zone_id, self.to_xml())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/route53/connection.py", line 475, in change_rrsets
body)
boto.route53.exception.DNSServerError: DNSServerError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/"><Error>    <Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidChangeBatch</Code><Message>Tried to create an alias that targets <alias_dns_name>., type A in zone <alias_hosted_zone_id>, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone</Message></Error><RequestId>afhh08-ckki9f2b5</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: *the alias target name does not lie within the target zone* ... I'm not sure I understand what's confusing about this.  Either elbName or elbZone is wrong.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for quickly replying. I was using wrong elbZone

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming into this error, the correct way to get the Hosted Zone ID varies for different target types. To find the correct hosted Zone ID, go to [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-1.html#aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-1-properties), scroll down to HostedZoneId and look for your target type.

In this particular case, if you're using an ALB or NLB, you need the CanonicalHostedZoneID attribute of said LB. If it's a Classic LB, you need the CanonicalHostedZoneNameID attribute.

Comment: You saved me tons of time. I was able to get it done by using the Hosted Zone from within the ELB resource. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can find Alias Host zone id from AWS Route53 console.

just try to create a sample alias record ( LoadBalancer, Cloudfront , ..) , and choose your region , Alias hosted zone Id will be shown in bottom

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the right `alias_hosted_zone_id` I went to the console and started creating the zone manually, when I passed the ELB DNS name in the field, the `alias_hosted_zone_id` showed up so I got it and put in my code. Hope this helps.